# Can't connect to remote Mysql server from php

Tags: php, mysql, linux, centos

- Client System: CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)
- Client Ip: 222.222.222.222
- http://test.com looks onto ip 222.222.222.222
- Server system: Gentoo Base System release 1.12.13
- Server ip: 111.111.111.111

Script for connect:

```
$connection = new \mysqli('111.111.111.111', 'user', 'password', 'db');
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo "Error: {$connection->connect_error}"; 
}
else {
    echo "Server Info: {$connection->server_info}";
}
```

When I'm trying to open in browser "http://test.com/test.php", I get:

```
Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '111.111.111.111' (13)
```

... but when I'm starting this script from command line on the server 222.222.222.222, I have another result:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/reporter/test.php
Server Info: 5.5.14-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log
```

Directly connection from command line also correct:

```
mysql -h 111.111.111.111 -u user -p -P 3306
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 25236357
Server version: 5.5.14-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log MySQL Enterprise Server - Advanced Edition (Commercial)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle, Monty Program Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

## Answer


Problem with client's environment - Selinux in Centos. Command fo fix it:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Comment: check for things like firewalls, suhosin/selinux blocking things, blah blah blah.

Comment: Pretty sure error 13 is a permissions thing. Double-check the password in the PHP just to be sure?

Comment: Why do you have a backslash in this line - `new \mysqli('111.11`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard global namespace, likely unnecessary but good practice I feel... just in case he has declared a new mysqli function within the current namespace. See examples here http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php

Comment: **Marc B**, user is exists, ports opened - I can connect remotely connect to DB. I can connect to even use same file, but only from cimmand line and I don't know reason of this behaviour.


**rjdown**, user and password is correct - I'm starting same script from browser and from command line but connection is establishsing only from  command line.

Answer (score 7):

Problem with client's environment - Selinux in Centos.
Command fo fix it:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!